# Avoid duplicate rows in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I use the following SQL query on SQL Server 2008 to select rows from `products` and `categories` tables.

```
SELECT products.idProduct,  sku, description, listPrice, 
   smallImageUrl, isBundleMain, rental, visits 
FROM products, categories_products 
WHERE products.idProduct = categories_products.idProduct 
AND categories_products.idCategory = "& pIdCategory&" 
AND listHidden=0 
AND active=-1 
AND idStore = " &pIdStore& "
ORDER BY description
```

The problem is that some rows are duplicate. Those duplicates are generally determined by `products.idProduct` column, so I want to change the  query so that the same `products.idProduct` doesn't appear twice, means for example one of the rows has `products.idProduct = 3438` and the other row has same product id as well only one of the `products.idProduct` gets displayed

Comment: Please qualify your select list so that we can determine which field is coming from which table (e.g.: tablename.sku, tablename.description, etc.).  Otherwise, it is impossible to tell if a `DISTINCT` like some have suggested would fix this.  Also, please provide sample result set (showing the duplicate records).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use distinct. Try below

```
SELECT distinct 
  products.idProduct, sku, description, listPrice, smallImageUrl, 
  isBundleMain, rental, visits 
FROM products, categories_products 
WHERE products.idProduct=categories_products.idProduct 
  AND categories_products.idCategory="& pIdCategory&" 
  AND listHidden=0 AND active=-1 
  AND idStore=" &pIdStore& "  
ORDER BY description
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**20 years** ago!). ***Please*** stop using it

Comment: Bad habits to kick: using DISTINCT when there is an underlying data quality or modelling issue. I would say this is a worse habit than join syntax.

Answer (score 3):

> Use `DISTINCT` as shown below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT products.idProduct, 
       sku, description, listPrice, 
       smallImageUrl, isBundleMain, rental, visits 
FROM products, categories_products 
WHERE products.idProduct = categories_products.idProduct 
AND categories_products.idCategory = "& pIdCategory&" 
AND listHidden = 0 AND active = -1 
AND idStore =" &pIdStore& "  
ORDER BY description
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**20 years** ago!). ***Please*** stop using it

Answer (score 3):

Use DISTINCT in your select query on your fields.